# Как сделать что бы несколько функций работали одновременно python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть файл `bot.py`:

```
import xxx


class Bot:
    def run(self):

        client = xxx.Client()

        client.login(email="email", password="password")

        subclient = xxx.SubClient(comId="id", profile=client.profile)

        oldMessages = []

        with open("oldMessages.txt", "r") as oldFile:
            for messageId in oldFile.read().split("\n")[:-1]:
                oldMessages.append(messageId)

        while True:
            readChat = ["chatid"]

            for chatId in readChat:
                msg = subclient.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatId, size=10)
                for message, messageId, author in zip(msg.content, msg.messageId, msg.author.nickname):
                    if not messageId in oldMessages:
                        print(chatId, author, message)

                        # "!ping" comnand
                        if str(message).startswith("!ping"):
                            subclient.send_message(chatId, "Pong!")

                        oldMessages.append(messageId)
                        with open("oldMessages.txt", "a") as oldFile:
                            oldFile.write(messageId + "\n")
                            oldFile.close()

    def run2(self):

        client = xxx.Client()

        client.login(email="email", password="password")

        subclient = xxx.SubClient(comId="id", profile=client.profile)

        oldMessages = []

        with open("oldMessages.txt", "r") as oldFile:
            for messageId in oldFile.read().split("\n")[:-1]:
                oldMessages.append(messageId)

        while True:
            readChat = ["chatid"]

            for chatId in readChat:
                msg = subclient.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatId, size=10)
                for message, messageId, author in zip(msg.content, msg.messageId, msg.author.nickname):
                    if not messageId in oldMessages:
                        print(chatId, author, message)

                        # "!ping" comnand
                        if str(message).startswith("!ping"):
                            subclient.send_message(chatId, "Pong!")

                        oldMessages.append(messageId)
                        with open("oldMessages.txt", "a") as oldFile:
                            oldFile.write(messageId + "\n")
                            oldFile.close()
```

И файл `main.py`:

```
from lib.bot import Bot

# Initialize the bot
bot = Bot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("START")
    bot.run()
    bot.run2()
```

Как можно сделать так, что бы функции `run` и `run2` работали одновременно?

Comment: Стоит метка `async-await`. Вам принципиально использовать именно этот механизм? Или можно дать ответ с простыми потоками?

Comment: Не принципиально

Comment: ответил, проверьте. Примите, если помогло в достаточной степени.

Comment: А они как-то взаимодействуют? Почему это не 2 разные программы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот ответ с использованием модуля `threading`:

```python
from lib.bot import Bot
from threading import Thread

# Initialize the bot
bot = Bot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("START")

    # Создаём два потока для каждого из методов
    t1 = Thread(target=bot.run)
    t2 = Thread(target=bot.run2)

    t1.start() # Запустили один метод на выполнение в потоке
    t2.start() # Не дожидаясь окончания первого, запустили второй на выполнение в другом потоке

    t1.join() # Теперь ждём завершения первого (второй при этом тоже выполняется)
    t2.join() # Ждём завершения второго (если второй завершится раньше первого, ожидания просто не будет)
```

P.S. [Вот](https://dev-gang.ru/article/mnogopotocznost-v-python-t2bkyunvku/), вроде бы, неплохая статья про многопоточность в целом и в Python в частности.